# How to retrieve wishlists from Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I retrieve wishlists and items in the cart from Amazon?

The documentation for Product Advertisement API does not talk about wishlists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could write a custom web **scraper** that takes the username/password as inputs and uses it to **scrape** the information from the wishlist after logging in with the credentials at hand. It might not be the best solution, but I'm sure it is possible. It might a little bit on tinkering with the raw HTML etc.

Also, you run the risk of the website changing the structure of the page. You could have some sort of checksum hash of the structure stored in your persistent store, failing which, you would refrain from **scraping** the site.

Comment: I did consider a scrapper as the wishlists are not exposed. But I am concerned about a possible down time for the app if the web UI changes drastically. Thanks for the response though. I am going to look into this.

Comment: You could add some smarts to let youself know when the UI changes. Maybe like  a service that checks periodically whether the UI checksum matches the one in hand and if it doesn't maybe, its time to revisit. Going the API route is the best way, but if that is not there and if you so want it done, you should consider alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't, as the API does not allow you to get any personal information from the user, and the wishlist is personal.

You should never find yourself in need of a user login to Amazon to be able to do what you want with the API. To get to a wishlist would requires just that....

Sorry for a negative answer, still hope it helps.

Bernard

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case. What if i were to write an app for amazon where the user wants to login and see his wishlist to purchase an item? Are you saying that this is impossible?!!!

Comment: With Amazon Advertising API, for what I know, yes, it's impossible, for a good reason: It's an ADVERTISING API, that is, you're supposed to bring clients to Amazon, not the contrary... :-)

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Please let me know if there is any other API which could be used to get the list of items in wishlists and carts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for scraping your Amazon wishlist (it will not work with the items in the cart, but will work with the wishlist).

https://github.com/doitlikejustin/amazon-wish-lister